# Handling URL routing with Apache and React Router

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, react-router-dom

I have a pair of apps which will be running on a shared Apache host. The apps are housed in a common directory on the server. Each application is housed within a "build" directory within its main directory. The `client` directory should be the default display, while `admin` should display at example.com/app/admin. And, to further complicate matters, `admin` uses React Router for its internal routing.

Here's a visual representation of the goal:

```
admin
|- build
   |- index.html (example.com/app/admin, example.com/app/admin/page1, etc.)
client
|- build
   |- index.html (example.com/app)
.htaccess
```

So I need to load the target pages while also enabling React Router to handle the routing for `admin`. I've tried about every combination of RewriteCond and RewriteRule I can think of in the .htaccess, but no luck so far. I feel like I'm getting closer with the rules below, but I'm still not quite there.

```
// .htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/build
RewriteRule ^admin$ admin/build [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/client/build|/admin)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ client/build [L]
</IfModule>
```

This shows /build in the address bar, and any request to /admin/(.*) fails to redirect the .css and .js file requests to the build folder (so it is instead looking for /admin/static/css/ instead of /admin/build/static/css), although they load successfully on requests to /admin.

EDIT: Changed "App1" to "client" and "App2" to "admin"; masking those serves no purpose, and the fact that the directory shares a name with the page might somehow be relevant.

Comment: How do you try to load your assets from `/admin/(.*)`? aka, what is the path it's trying to access before even getting redirected? - Look at the network tab in Chrome developer tools and check for 404s in there.

Comment: No redirects on those files at all, just 404s.

Comment: But what path do they initially point to?

Comment: @Capsule The document is pointing to `/admin/page1`, and the .css/.js resources are pointing to `/admin/static/...`.

Comment: You don't have any rule to rewrite/redirect those tho. `RewriteRule ^admin$ admin/build [L]` only rewrites `/admin`, not `/admin(.*)`

Comment: @Capsule Correct. This is the part I'm trying to get help with. I know why my current solution doesn't work, but the many configurations I've tried all have various issues. I have to get all of the page URLs to redirect to the main index.html file in the build directory, but the static resources have to be routed into the correct folder when the index.html requests them. Plus, the current iteration is rewriting the URL in the address bar, so that's going to prevent the Router from detecting which page it's supposed to display.

Comment: There's something I don't get. You say everything lives under `/app`, but you use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/build`. `%{REQUEST_URI} ` will always start with `/app`, not `/admin`

Comment: @Capsule That's because everything is currently living in the root directory of a virtual host in my development environment. This isn't my forte (obviously), so correct me if I'm wrong, but once I move to production, don't I just need to change the RewriteBase from `/` to `/app`?

Comment: Rule number 1: never set different paths between dev and prod, you will end up will all kinds of nasty surprises when it comes to rewriting, absolute vs relative paths for assets, and different behaviours with server paths (document_root + / + the rest of your path vs document_root + app + the rest of your path) if using any server side tech. Theorically, yes, you can change you RewriteBase but it will not solve absolute paths that are not rewritten, or server side paths. Also it forces you to maintain this Rewritebase change between the 2 envs.

Comment: @Capsule Fair enough. So I can update the structure so that I don't have this inconsistency. But I still don't have an answer for what needs to happen to get my rewrites working, and I especially don't understand why the URLs I'm currently rewriting are changing in the address bar.

Comment: Did you try to rewrite to actual file instead of the path that will match the index? So, `admin/build/index.html` and `client/build/index.html`. You might have some redirect happening because of the missing trailing slash.

Comment: @Capsule Thanks, that ended up being the key.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this sorted out. Final rewrite below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/admin [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/admin/build
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]
RewriteRule admin/\w*/?$ admin/build/index.html [L]
RewriteRule admin/(.+)$ admin/build/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(?:/app/client/build|/app/admin/build)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ client/build/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```